# Unable to save stripe customer ID

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

As the title suggests, I am unable to save my customer ID in my database using Stripe. I am creating a registration form so when a user signs up to the site they will have a Stripe customer ID so future payments can be made. However, when the user registers, all data will is saved into the database except the customer ID.

```
        // Create a Customer
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
          "source" => $token,
          "description" => "Example customer")
        );
         echo "customer ID is ".$customer->id;
         $newCustomer = $customer->id;
        // Charge the Customer instead of the card
        \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => 250, // amount in cents, again
          "currency" => "gbp",
          "customer" => $customer->id)
        );
}
?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="login">
      <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-6 login-do">
            <div>
      <select name="title" type="text" class="dropdown-select">
          <option value="">Title</option>
          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      </select>
    </div>

      <div class="login-mail">
        <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter your first name')"/>
        <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="login-mail">
        <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter your last name')" />
      </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
          <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" />
          <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
          <input name="pass" type="text" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
          <input name="retyped_password" type="text" type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" />
        </div>

      <a class="news-letter " href="#">
  <label class="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ><i> </i>Forget Password</label>
  </a>
<label class="hvr-skew-backward">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</label>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6 login-right">
<a href="login.html" class="hvr-skew-backward">Login</a>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"> </div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
      <?php
      if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $retyped_password = $_POST['retyped_password'];
        $newCustomer = $_POST['newCus'];
```

Comment: Where does `$_POST['newCus']` come from? There's no such field in the form.

Comment: Is that supposed to contain the customer ID? Put it in a hidden field.

Comment: Your code block makes it look like everything is in one file, but this would not make sense. Is the last `<?php` block (which is not closed btw) a separate file, presumably `register.php`? This seems implied by the code but you need to note this verbally *and* use a separate code block for each file, or your question is unclear. I agree with @Barmar that you need to pass the customer ID in a hidden field. You cannot pass a whole customer object through an HTML form. The names `newCus` and `$newCustomer` are unclear, as the naming seems to imply they are customer objects.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you expecting the ID to come from? You are creating a customer, but not including their ID at the top of your code. Should it not be included there?

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example customer",
  "id" => "123")
);
```

Comment: Stripe's server generates the ID when you call the `create` API.

Comment: yes I figured that - but you don't seem to be including it in the array when the new $customer array is being created - but you are then calling the $curstomer aray to utilise it later on. and also in the php code at the end you are not listing it - but that could be because you are only showing a portion of that code.

Comment: How can you put it in the call? You don't know the ID that Stripe will assign to the customer until after you make the call. It's a string like `cus_5XoGngLVDGWhvH` that comes back as part of the returned data.

Comment: BTW, I'm not the OP.

Comment: laffing - missed that - sorry

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be something like this (just pseudo-code):

1. Look up the user in your user database.
2. If the user already has a saved Stripe customer ID, set $customer_id from that.
3. If not:

   1. Call `\Stripe\Customer::create()`
   2. Update the user database to add the customer ID.
   3. Set $customer_id from the returned customer object.
4. Create the charge using $customer_id